# MailPoet Cron Job in Plesk 11.5

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, plesk

I am trying to run a cron job URL through Plesk 11.5 on my shared hosting space and not getting through. All I want to do is to run a URL every minute. The URL looks like [this](http://www.mydomain.in/wp-cron.php?d5af4554fb95c294ca30cc31bb832200&action=wysija_cron&process=all).

This URL is a MailPoetURL which send all the emails in a queue when it's run.

The plesk control for scheduled tasks looks like this:

[image]

I have `Path to executable file` confirmed by the hosting but I need what I need to use in the `Arguments`. I have tried following arguments which didn't work for me:

```
wget [[httplink mentioned above]]    
wget -q -O /dev/null [[httplink mentioned above]]    
/usr/bin/wget -q -O /dev/null [[httplink mentioned above]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see your server OS is windows, so wget is not option for you.

Instead you can create PHP script inside of /httpdocs folder with content like

```
<?php
    file_get_contents('http://<your full url here>');
```

and put path to this script in "Arguments" like:

[image: plesk cron task call php on Windows]

**Note 1:** I'm note sure that you have to use "php-cgi.exe", but just "php.exe".

**Note 2:** Use "Run Now" to check it immediately.